# Netty UDP broadcast receiver works on one NIC but not on another - why?

Tags: java, linux, udp, netty, broadcast

Hi – I wonder if anyone can help me. I’m using Netty 4.1.9 to send UDP messages between two Linux machines:

- Both machines are attached via 3 separate NICs to the same 3 networks.
- I have some working code that sends the messages from one to the other and that is received okay.
- I then changed the code to force the UDP traffic onto a different network, out through a different NIC on the sender.
- The sending works, I can see the traffic on the different network, but now the netty receiver can’t see the traffic.

As far as I can see the receiver code shouldn’t care which NIC the data comes in on, so I don’t understand what the issue is.

I’m sure the data arrives at the receiver host on the correct NIC because running “*tshark -i* ” on the receiver shows the traffic on the correct network, with the correct destination port, and expected length.

The broadcast address I'm using in both cases is 255.255.255.255.

Here's the code for the setting up the receiver channel, this code works fine when the traffic arrives on the first NIC, but not when it arrives on the other:

```
public Channel createReceivingChannel(final int port,
                                      final EventLoopGroup myGroup) throws InterruptedException
{
   return new Bootstrap()
            .group(myGroup)
            .channelFactory(new ChannelFactory<NioDatagramChannel>()
            {
                @Override
                public NioDatagramChannel newChannel()
                {
                    return new NioDatagramChannel(InternetProtocolFamily.IPv4);
                }
            })
            .handler(new ReceiverInitializer(this.protocolConfig))

            .bind(port).sync().channel();
}
```

Here's the sender code that works with the receiver, but puts the UDP messages on the wrong network:

```
public Channel createSendingChannel(      final NetworkAddress localAddress,
                                          final int port,
                                          final EventLoopGroup myGroup) throws InterruptedException
{
    return new Bootstrap()
            .group(myGroup)
            .channelFactory(new ChannelFactory<NioDatagramChannel>()
            {
                @Override
                public NioDatagramChannel newChannel()
                {
                    return new NioDatagramChannel(InternetProtocolFamily.IPv4);
                }
            })
            .localAddress(localAddress.address, port)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true)
            .handler(new SenderInitializer(this.protocolConfig))

            .bind(0).sync().channel();
}
```

And here's my sender code that puts the data on the right network, but the receiver above can't see it:

```
public Channel createSendingChannel(
                                    final NetworkAddress localAddress,
                                    final int port,

                                    final EventLoopGroup myGroup) throws InterruptedException
{
   final InetSocketAddress localSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress.address, port);

    return new Bootstrap()
            .group(myGroup)
            .channelFactory(new ChannelFactory<NioDatagramChannel>()
            {
                @Override
                public NioDatagramChannel newChannel()
                {
                    return new NioDatagramChannel(InternetProtocolFamily.IPv4);
                }
            })
            .localAddress(localAddress.address, port)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true)
            .handler(new SenderInitializer(this.protocolConfig))

            .bind(localSocketAddress).sync().channel(); // difference here to bind the sender to correct NIC
}
```

Any help gratefully received at this stage. I'm stuck.

Many thanks in advance,

Michael.